# Using ng-model-options with ngModelController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to delay validation of an custom textbox component. I only want to validate the input on blur. The existing component does not use ng-model inside the input but uses the ngModelController inside the controller of the custom component like so:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-required="true"/>
```

Can I still use ng-model-options onblur to delay the binding between the template and the controller?

If I'm using ngModelController inside component controller and not using ng-model inside the input element, can I still use ng-model-options in some way to delay input binding? Or is there another clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/28j92bzk/

Use `ng-blur`

`<input type="text" name="name" ng-required="true" ng-blur="validate($event)"/>`

```
$scope.validate = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value); // value of input
  // use your logic here
}
```